# cuda nvprof for mex file

Tags: cuda, profiling, mex

My program consists of a Matlab file (.m) and a mex-cuda file(.cu). It starts with Matlab, then the Matlab file calls the mex-cuda file.

I want to get profiling the performance in the mex-cuda file using 'nvprof' command-line. I know that for regular CUDA program, we simply use (in Unix):

```
$nvprof file.out
```

However, the mex-cuda file now is called from matlab, not from the shell anymore. Is there a way to use 'nvprof' command-line for this mex-cuda file?

Comment: If you run matlab from the command line, try `nvprof "matlab < myfile.m"`

Comment: This is a perfect solution. It runs well without using the quotation " symbols. Just --> $nvprof matlab < myfile.m <--. Thanks a lot Robert.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Consider answering this. As easy as it seems, it is a brilliant feature for us MATLAB users.

Answer (score 3):

If you run matlab from the command line, try

```
nvprof "matlab < myfile.m"
```

The quotes may be unnecessary,  i.e.this may work as well:

```
nvprof matlab < myfile.m
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to add nvprof in matlab path? Where is it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This blog explains how to profile CUDA kernels from MATLAB.

http://meerkat.gr/matlab-profile-cuda.html

It should work with CUDA-MEX as well.